# disable case sensitive in visual studio solution explorer

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, visual-studio, solution-explorer

In the visual studio solution explorer, when a word is written in lower case then

the solution explorer filters the word as not case-sensitive but if one letter is

written in upper case then it will be case-sensitive.

Can I customize case-sensitive options for either upper or lower cases?

For Example, can I disable case-sensitive for uppercase?

Comment: It may be repaired one day: https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/57952/solution-explorer-file-filter-is-case-sensitive-bu.html

Answer (score 25):

As far as I can tell, there is no setting to change this behavior but understanding it seems to be the most important thing.

I'm in Visual Studio Professional 2017 v15.9.14. I've been thinking I'm going crazy thinking the search seems to sometimes be case-sensitive and sometimes not. I finally realized that **for file names**, if I type the search string *all* lowercase, then it does a case-insensitive search. As soon as I add a capital to my search string, it switches to case-sensitive.

For code members, it seems to be always case-insensitive.

Comment: Same behaviour in VS 2019 16.11.16. Suspect functionality since the behaviour is hidden. A developer who types "Fred" expects to find "fred.cpp" and "FRED.h"...but instead finds neither! As with other search features such as `Quick Find` (Ctrl + F) case sensitivity should be an option. Or, since this is rarely used and focused on `Solution Explorer`, don't bother creating a setting and just be case-insensitive.

Comment: 3 years later, this is still the behavior in Visual Studio 2022!

Answer (score 15):

If you want to search without  match case, in search field **type only lowercase** characters.
So characher case will ignore

[Example VS2022](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Jo0pV.png)

Comment: you are grate man

Comment: That should be the accepted answer. Work smart not hard. Works fine.

Answer (score 0):

You can use ReSharper short-cut: "CTRL + SHIFT + T" to filter instead of Visual Studio. Moreover I think there no way to customize case-sensitive options of VS behavior.

Comment: @i.Bahrampour That's a paid extension.